# General::ivar: 3 is not a valid variable. error when calculating Ricci tensor

Tags: tensors

I'm having troubles when evaluating the Ricci tensor in Mathematica.

```
coord = {t, x, y, z}
n = 4
metric = {{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, a[t]^2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, a[t]^2, 0}, {0, 0, 
   0, a[t]^2}}

inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]]

chr[a_, b_, c_] := Simplify[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 
     1\), \(4\)]\(\((1/2)\) inversemetric[\([a, 
      j]\)] \((D[metric[\([j, c]\)], coord[\([\)\(b\)\(]\)]] + 
      D[metric[\([j, b]\)], coord[\([\)\(c\)\(]\)]] - 
      D[metric[\([\)\(b, c\)\(]\)], coord[\([j]\)]])\)\)\)]

Riemann[y_, b_, c_, d_] := 
 Simplify[D[chr[y, d, b], coord[[c]]] - 
   D[chr[y, c, b], coord[[d]]] + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(l = 1\), \(4\)]\((chr[y, c, l]*
      chr[l, b, d])\)\) - \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(l = 1\), \(4\)]\((chr[y, d, l]*
      chr[l, b, c])\)\)]
R[b_, d_] := Simplify[Sum[Riemann[y, b, y, d], {y, 1, n}]]
R[1, 1]
```

When I execute `R[1,1]` I get this error:

```
General::ivar: 3 is not a valid variable.
```

How can I solve this error?
Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what is happening here, but `R[b_, d_] := Simplify[Riemann[1, b, 1, d] + Riemann[2, b, 2, d] + Riemann[3, b, 3, d] + Riemann[4, b, 4, d]]` is aq temporary fix.

Comment: Yup, this is what I did to overcome the problem! But I was curious to find out why there is this sort of issue when using Sum. Thanks

Comment: @StefanoManzoni Use in the last line `R[b_, d_] := Simplify[Sum[Riemann[i, b, i, d], {i, 1, n}]]`

Comment: @AlexTrounev thanks, this partially solves the problem: the output is not the same as doing`Riemann[1, b, 1, d] + Riemann[2, b, 2, d] + Riemann[3, b, 3, d] + Riemann[4, b, 4, d]`

Comment: All I get is output which contains derivatives of constants which are not set equal to zero, so my result is not correct if I use the `Sum`

Comment: Yes, the comment by @AlexTrounev works for me.  If not for you, run code in a fresh notebook.  You may have old definitions causing problems too.

Comment: Yes you are right, the solution proposed by @AlexTrounev solved my problem! Thanks

Comment: always take coordinates {x,y,z,t} not {t,x,y,z}.

Comment: @apk why should I use that? Is it better?

Comment: @StefanoManzoni In general relativity, we take {0,1,2,3} as {t,r,/theta,/phi} coordinates. So if we take {r,/theta,/phi,t} we can work with same notation like 1 as r, 2 as /theta except that 4 is the time coordinate here for which in GR we use 0.

Comment: I have done reimann ricci calculations in mathematica many times and everytime I use {r,theta,phi,t} not {t, r ,theta,phi}. I myself feel it is better. Also, I suggest you to take both ways {t,r,theta,phi}  and {r,theta,phi,t} and just check if mathematica is giving correct answer. For {t,r, theta, phi} I think it will not always give correct results. It is better to check yourself for your own satisfaction. But as per my knowledge, {r,theta,phi,t}is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check result we can use following code

```
    Clear [coord, metric, inversemetric, affine, riemann, ricci, scalar, \
    t, x, y, z]
    
    n = 4;
    coord = {t, x, y, z};
    metric = {{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, a[t]^2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, a[t]^2, 0}, {0, 0, 
          0, a[t]^2}}; inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]];
    
    affine := 
      affine = Simplify[
        Table[(1/2)*
          Sum[inversemetric[[i, 
             s]]*(D[metric[[s, j]], coord[[k]]] + 
              D[metric[[s, k]], coord[[j]]] - 
              D[metric[[j, k]], coord[[s]]]), {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 
          1, n}, {k, 1, n}]];
    
    
    riemann := 
      riemann = 
       Simplify[
        Table[D[affine[[i, j, l]], coord[[k]]] - 
          D[affine[[i, j, k]], coord[[l]]] + 
          Sum[affine[[s, j, l]]*affine[[i, k, s]] - 
            affine[[s, j, k]]*affine[[i, l, s]], {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, 
          n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}]];
    
    ricci := ricci = 
      Simplify[Table[
        Sum[riemann[[i, j, i, l]], {i, 1, n}], {j, 1, n}, {l, 1, n}]]
    
    scalar = Simplify[
      Sum[inversemetric[[i, j]]*ricci[[i, j]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]];
```

We can evaluate

```
    ricci
    
    Out[]= {{-((3 (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t])/a[t]), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
      2 Derivative[1][a][t]^2 + a[t] (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t], 0, 0}, {0, 
      0, 2 Derivative[1][a][t]^2 + a[t] (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t], 0}, {0, 
      0, 0, 2 Derivative[1][a][t]^2 + a[t] (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]}}
```

We can also evaluate Ricci tensor with author's code

```
Clear [coord, metric, inversemetric, t, x, y, z]
coord = {t, x, y, z};
n = 4;
metric = {{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, a[t]^2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, a[t]^2, 0}, {0, 0, 
       0, a[t]^2}};

inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]];

chr[a_, b_, c_] := Simplify[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 
     1\), \(4\)]\(\((1/2)\) inversemetric[\([a, 
      j]\)] \((D[metric[\([j, c]\)], coord[\([b]\)]] + 
      D[metric[\([j, b]\)], coord[\([c]\)]] - 
      D[metric[\([b, c]\)], coord[\([j]\)]])\)\)\)]

Riemann[y_, b_, c_, d_] := 
  Simplify[D[chr[y, d, b], coord[[c]]] - 
      D[chr[y, c, b], coord[[d]]] + \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(l = 1\), \(4\)]\((chr[y, c, l]*
      chr[l, b, d])\)\) - \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(l = 1\), \(4\)]\((chr[y, d, l]*
      chr[l, b, c])\)\)]
R[b_, d_] := Simplify[Sum[Riemann[i, b, i, d], {i, 1, n}]]


 Table[R[i, j], {i, n}, {j, n}]

Out[]= {{-((3 (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t])/a[t]), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  2 Derivative[1][a][t]^2 + a[t] (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t], 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 2 Derivative[1][a][t]^2 + a[t] (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t], 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 2 Derivative[1][a][t]^2 + a[t] (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]}}
```

Finally we can check that expressions `ricci` and `R` are identical.